# Html markup in cakephp's $html->link, eg. $html->link('<span>Hey</span>')?

Tags: cakephp

I have this block of code in a cakephp .ctp file:

```
<h1>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Hello <span>Stack Overflow</span>',
        array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home'));  ?>
</h1>
```

But instead of the html being formatted, I'm seeing it literally:

```
<h1><a href="/rrweb/www/hub/pages/home">
Hello &lt;span&gt;Stack Overflow&lt;/span&gt;</a></h1>
```

Any idea's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to [disable HTML entity conversion](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1435/Inserting-Well-Formatted-elements#link-1442):

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Hello <span>Stack Overflow</span>',
    array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home'),
    array('escape' => FALSE)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```
echo $this->Html->link('Hello', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home')).' '.$this->Html->tag('span', $this->Html->link('Stack Overflow', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home')), array());
```