# Customize $this->Html->link() As per HTML

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, helper

i have this html code, and am having problem to create link on cakephp !

this is the html code!

```
 <li>
       <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> 
        Morris
      </a>

    </li>
```

And i want to make it like this, cakephp way!

```
<li>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('list'),
              array(
                'controller'=>'transactions',
                'action'=>'index'
              )

           ); ?>
</li>
```

but am having problem with this, where and how i will put this:

i want it to be like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9K-whE0SuvQkhUQy14T2lacjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is issue now ? Please always clarify sir.

Comment: Care to check Answer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html markup in cakephp's $html->link, eg. $html->link('<span>Hey</span>')?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324609/html-markup-in-cakephps-html-link-eg-html-linkspanhey-span)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
echo $this->Html->link(
   '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>',
    array(
      'controller'=>'transactions',
      'action'=>'index'
    ),
    array(
      'escape'=>false  //NOTICE THIS LINE ***************
    )
);
```

Comment: @NoNation HI you can Accept answer (Green Check button) if it solves issue. Thanks