# Convert html link to cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How would I convert this html:

```
<a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
```

for cakephp language?

Like from using and enjoying something like:

> $this->Html->link('foo',
>   array('controller'=>'bar','action'=>'display'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that while Stackoverflow is not a "Write this for me" or "convert this for me" type of community, this is a short and straightforward question so I'll answer it. Since CakePHP doesn't support custom HTML tag creation, you'll just need to put the literal in your link() call and [disable HTML entity conversion, as detailed in the docs.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link) It would look something like:

```
$this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard', 'index.html', array('escape'=>FALSE));
```

That should achieve exactly what you want. A similar question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324609/html-markup-in-cakephps-html-link-eg-html-linkspanhey-span), and as always please RTM.